# Does anyone know how to access data from another farm?

Tags: navigation

So basically the problem is: I have one farm that I have limited access to. I need to access that farm to get information to another farm. I.E Top navigation needs to be in sync w/the other farms. I just want to know if this is possible using c# code behind?

Answer (score 2):

In 2010 and 2013, you have the SharePoint Client Object Model.  Using this you can create C# code that runs outside of the context of the farm being accessed.  For some examples, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many posibilities, with regard to what kind of data you try to access. In your case, because you are interested only in navigation you could use a similar approach as described for the "Cross site collection navigations" - see here http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/sharepoint2010-custom-navigation-provider-cross-sitecollection/ - the key being the part making a simple WebRequest retrieve and serialize as JSON (many JQuery components can use this as data source).

Another approach is to connect to the Web Services of that particular Farm direclty - but it also means that you need to figure our what Web Application / Site Collection you are actually targetting - see here http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx. I'm not actually aware whether you get a "Navigation" related web service, but you could find all here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx

Finally, i believe you also need to understand what "navigation" you are actually targeting, as the actual navigation is always handled via navigation providers - explained quite well here http://sadomovalex.blogspot.ch/2010/02/basics-of-navigation-in-sharepoint.html